# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-transactions, hibernate-annotations

I'm trying to configure org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource as bean in web.xml under a tomcat project using tomcat 6 and postgresql
9.1

my servletdispacher.xml

`

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />




<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/car" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="123" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>DAOModel.Tblusers</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="DAOModel.Tblusers" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`
and error which get :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me for the tomcat6 package on Mint 15. The installation had `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/commons-pool.jar -> ../../java/commons-pool.jar` but `/usr/share/java/commons-pool.jar -> commons-pool-1.5.6.jar` was broken. Copying it from my local Maven repo `sudo cp ~/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.6/commons-pool-1.5.6.jar /usr/share/java` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

It seems the 'commons-pool' jar is not being deployed. If you are using eclipse, you can check which jars are deployed by going to the project's properties, and clicking Deployment Assembly.

Comment: i use from netbeans and exists commons-pool2-2.1.jar in web-inf\lib

Comment: Ok, I could be wrong. But this error from your question title (NoClassDefinitionFound) means that in all of the jars in your deployment, none of them have the "org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool" class. I recommend using the tool "Tattletale" to see what's going on inside your project jars.

Answer (score 2):

May be your `commons-pool-x.x.x.jar` is not present in your lib folder in deployed folder this can be solved by copying this jar file in `apache-tomcat-7.0.54\lib` folder

Answer (score -1):

I too faced some problem, in my repo commons-pool2-2.1.jar is not downloaded properly. we need to download correct jar.