# How to register connection pool in tomcat with JSP?

Tags: java, database, jsp, tomcat, connection-pooling

I want to connect connection-pool(DBCP?) to mysql-db and register in tomcat.

So, I install some of *.jar files(DHCP, Pool, Collection) into `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib"`.

Then, I execute my code below, but, it doesn't work.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.*"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.*"%>

<%
    GenericObjectPool objectPool = new GenericObjectPool();
    DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC",
        "root", "****"
    );
    new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, objectPool);

    PoolingDriver driver = new PoolingDriver();
    driver.registerPool("/webdb_pool", objectPool);
%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Pool is registered!!!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

And the errors are:

> `The constructor GenericObjectPool() is undefined`
>
> `The constructor PoolableConnectionFactory(DriverManagerConnectionFactory, GenericObjectPool) is undefined`

[image]

how to fix them..??

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191544/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-pool-impl-genericobjectpool ?

Comment: @Shubham that's problem it isn't suitable for my case... but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null);
DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
     new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(URL, username, password);
PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory =
     new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, connectionPool, null, 
         null, false, false);
poolingDataSource = new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);
```